# Grafana add new filter to the graph

Tags: grafana

Below is the metrics i used to populate graph on the panel. Now I want to filter the graph with a dropdown. **Mode[test,live]** .

```
sum(rate(seconds_count{product="$product", region="$region", job="$job", environment="$environment", deployment="$deployment", channel=~"$channel", class="com.test.Main", method="test", exception="none"}[$__interval])) by (method) * 60
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a variable of type `custom`, then enter your values deliminated by a comma `test,live`:

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nQZyD.png)

Add the variable to your query:

```
sum(rate(seconds_count{product="$product", region="$region", job="$job", environment="$environment", deployment="$deployment", channel=~"$channel", class="com.test.Main", method="$Mode", exception="none"}[$__interval])) by (method) * 60
```

For reference, [here are the docs for dashboard variables in Grafana.](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/variables/)

Edit:

Just had a thought. A better way to do this is to use the [`query` variable](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/datasources/prometheus/#query-variable). Use this query to grab all values of your desired label:

```
label_values(method)
```